# Geodjango __contained query. Postgis Operator @ not supported

Tags: django, postgis, geodjango

I have the following model :

```
class Share(models.Model):

    creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    source = models.PointField(geography=True, srid=4326)
```

from that I am trying to retrieve all rows where source is within the following recangle

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Polygon

xmin = sw_lng # is 11.1 
ymin = sw_lat # is 48.1
xmax = ne_lng # is 11.2
ymax = ne_lat # is 48.2      or whatever

bbox = (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
geom = Polygon.from_bbox(bbox)

queryset = Share.objects.filter(source__contained=geom)

for object in queryset:
    print ('gefunden [%s]' % (object.name))
```

But I do receive

```
ValueError: PostGIS geography does not support the "@" function/operator.
```

In the postgis doku @ is marked as implemented. Does anybody have a clue ?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved it .... source is of type "geography" which is not supported by "@" on postgis I have to use :

```
queryset = Share.objects.filter(source__coveredby=geom)
```

anyway ..

Comment: Man, thanks for posting this!
The most random error.